# Почему в Django обновления в БД не отображаются на сайте при использовании функции get_list_or_404() в контроллере?

Tags: python, django

После создания, удаления или изменения данных в базе при обновлении станицы никаких изменений не происходит, пока не перезагрузишь серевер. Проблема как я пронял в функции "get_list_or_404()", значение которой я передал в "queryset" контроллера. Если в queryset передать "models.Product.objects.all()", то все изменения сразу видны на сайте после обновления страницы. Версия Django 2.1.7, сервер запущен на локалке.

Может кто подскажет в чем причина?

Код контроллера:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_list_or_404, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from . import models, forms

class ProductList(ListView):

    context_object_name = 'query'

    template_name = 'products/index.html'

    queryset = get_list_or_404(models.Product)
```

Код url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.ProductList.as_view(), name='list'),

    path('create/', views.ProductCreate.as_view(), name='create'),

    path('<int:pk>/', views.product_detail, name='detail'),]
```

Шаблон:

```html
{% extends 'master.html' %}


{% load static %}

{% block page_title %}Title{% endblock %}

{% block page_static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'products/style.css' %}">
{% endblock %}


{% block page_content %}
    {% for item in query %}
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/media/{{ item.image }}" alt="{{ item.name }}">
            <a href="{% url 'products:detail'  item.id %}">
                <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
            </a>
            <h3>{{ item.cost }}</h3>

        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Вы используете `get_list_or_404()` только для того, чтобы представление перенаправляло на страницу 404 при пустом списке объектов?

Comment: @Andrey, да. Конкретно в этом случае список по любому будет полный, и нет необходимости обрабатывать ошибку, но все же что с этой функцией не так?

Comment: Я не знаю, что с ней не так, могу только предположить, что значением атрибута должен быть QuerySet, но эта функция возвращает список? Я предложил другое решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ListView есть атрибут `allow_empty`. Если присвоить ему значение `False`, то будет вызываться 404 при пустом списке. Попробуйте так:

```
class ProductList(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'query'
    template_name = 'products/index.html'
    model = models.Product
    allow_empty = False  # Показывать 404, если queryset пустой
```

Comment: Действительно, так исключать ошибку более корректно. С спасибо за ответ.